# Laravel remove attribute from recursive collection

Tags: recursion, laravel-5, model, eloquent

In my User model I have a recursive function which builds a tree based on my user object and it looks as it follows

```
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasreporters()->with(['children']);
    }

    public function hasreporters() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'reporting_to', 'acc_receiving_from_id', 'acc_reporting_to_id');
    }
```

than in my controller I get the data as it follows

```
$trees = User::with( 'children')
    ->where('display_off', 0)
    ->where('account_status', 'A')
    ->whereNotIn('ma_status', ['virtuell', 'freelancer'])
    ->where('account_id', 1867)
    ->get();


return response()->json($trees);
```

I have an avatar attribute represented as data-uri and I would like to remove from this query, how would I proceed?

the `forget` method did not worked for me in this case

Comment: Why can't you use `select()`?

Comment: Yes I ws trying select but destroys tho hole recursion.